# Derive child theme from separate theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework, 500-internal-error

Right now, I have a website that is using the Genesis theme. I'm trying to create a child theme, except I don't want to go through all the work of that. At the moment, I've downloaded a normal theme - gridz - and I want to make it a child theme.

What I've tried to do so far is add **Template: genesis** to the bottom of the style.css head as shown below.

```
  /*
Theme Name: Gridz
Theme URI: http://appswp.net/gridz-wordpress-theme/
Author: AppsWP
Author URI: http://www.appswp.net
Description: Pinterest like personal blogging theme powered by jQuery Masonry. Beautiful retina-ready and responsive theme with flexible layout. Tons of options to customize the theme according to your needs
Version: 1.0.5
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: light, white, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, left-sidebar, fluid-layout, responsive-layout, custom-colors, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, post-formats, sticky-post, translation-ready, theme-options
Text Domain: gridz
Template: genesis
*/
```

When I install the theme, it registers as such. However, when I try to activate the theme, the whole website comes up with an `HTTP 500 error`.

I feel as though the issue comes in the functions.php, but I don't know where the issue comes in. Now, the functions.php file is over 800 lines long, but I'll show just a single function as it may provide some insight into what's causing this error.

```
    /**
 * Filters Title for the Site
 */
function gridz_filter_wp_title($title) {
    $site_name = get_bloginfo('name');
    if(trim($title) != '') {
    $title = str_replace('&raquo;','',$title);
    $filtered_title = $title.' | '.$site_name;
    } else
    $filtered_title = $site_name;
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $site_description = get_bloginfo('description');
    if(trim($site_description) != '')
        $filtered_title .= ' | '.$site_description;
    }
    return $filtered_title;
}
```

As another note, there is some code at the top of every page as such:

```
/**
 * @package gridz
 */
```

I've tried taking out the code above, but the internal server error still occurs. At the moment, I have no idea as to what I should be doing next.

Comment: It looks like you want to use genesis parent framework but use another theme that is not a genesis child theme and make it into a child theme of Genesis. You can't do that. If you have a deep understanding of CSS you can re-style a Genesis child theme to look similar, but you can't use a parent theme as a child of a parent theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your target. If you want to create a child theme, it is quite easy and strightforward; just follow these simple rules: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Nothing to do with functions.php of the main theme which you should NEVER edit if you want to setup an independent child theme.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use genesis parent framework but use another theme that is not a genesis child theme and make it into a child theme of Genesis. You can't do that. If you have a deep understanding of CSS you can re-style a Genesis child theme to look similar, but you can't use a parent theme as a child of a parent theme.